# Both ugly URL and seo friendly URL are working. How to disable the ugly URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i am using RewriteRule to change the ugly URL to the seo friendly URL. But now both of the URLs are working simultaneously. How can u disable the ugly URL?

Comment: Too many different ways you could do it. canonical, 301 redirect, ... tell us about your setup/configuration and what you tried.

Comment: I am not sure which setup/configuration u mean, but this is my rewriterule RewriteRule ^test ?action=viewArticle&articleId=23 [NC,L]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to handle this kind of thing is to handle *routing* within PHP itself. There are many *router* libraries which map URLs to functions/classes/controllers *and vice versa*, which is really the sanest way to handle URLs. In this case, you'd just have one generic `RewriteRule` which rewrites *all* URLs into one canonical handler:

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php
```

`index.php` then handles all routing, and since it will only handle "pretty URLs" the ugly ones won't match any of its routes. Apache won't match any "ugly URLs" directly to files anymore with this rule in place.

For example, see http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html